# bash read does not wait for input

Tags: bash, ssh

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for some_host in $(cat some_list); do
    echo $some_host
    ssh $some_host sudo cat /etc/some.conf |grep -i something_to_grep
    printf "\nPut the input: " read some_input
    echo $some_input
    
done
```

When I run it, it just continues without waiting for my input. I need to copy/past something form ssh output for further action :/

Comment: change to `echo "Put the input: " ; read some_input`

Comment: You aren't running `read` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
printf "\nPut the input: " read some_input
```

to

```
read -p "Put the input: " some_input
```

## Example

```
for host in '1.1.1.100' '1.1.1.101' '1.1.1.102'
do
    read -p "Enter your input for ${host} " host_input
    echo "${host} says ${host_input}"
done
```